# How can I run ajax request on field exit?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have an ajax request which populates form data on submission. I'd like to adjust so that it populates when a form field (ex: ordernum) has an entered value. I've tried to adjust the coding to execute onChange but just get an error.

```
 function get_data() {
        // stop the form submitting
       // event.preventDefault();

        // grab the ID and send AJAX request if not (empty / only whitespace)
        var ID = this.elements.ordernum.value;
        if (/\S/.test(ID)) {
            ajax_request(this.action, {"action" : "fetch", "ordernum" : ID}, process_response);
        }
        else {
            alert("No ID supplied");
        }
    }

    // encapsulate the lot within a function scope called on document ready
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        // hook the submit action on the form

    var frm = document.getElementById("quick-form");
     frm.addEventListener("submit", frm_submit, false);

    /**
    * function to handle form submit, and request data from server
    * @param {Event} event
    */
    function frm_submit(event) {
        // stop the form submitting
        event.preventDefault();

        // grab the ID and send AJAX request if not (empty / only whitespace)
        var ID = this.elements.ordernum.value;
        if (/\S/.test(ID)) {
            ajax_request(this.action, {"action" : "fetch", "ordernum" : ID}, process_response);
        }
        else {
            alert("No ID supplied");
        }
    }
... blah ...
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.elements.ordernum')

 get_data (quick_form.php, line 36)

 onchange (quick_form.php, line 180)  with a onchange="get_data()"

Answer (score 0):

Based on all information you gave us, I recreated the following. No errors. They must be caused somewhere in the code you did not show us.

```js
///// This is a dummy, simulating what you may have there in real.

function ajax_request(a, b, c) {
  setTimeout(c, 500);
}


function process_response() {
  alert('Hurray!');
}

///// The original code (only reformated)

function get_data() {
  // stop the form submitting
  // event.preventDefault();

  // grab the ID and send AJAX request if not (empty / only whitespace)
  var ID = this.elements.ordernum.value;
  if (/\S/.test(ID)) {
    ajax_request(this.action, {"action" : "fetch", "ordernum" : ID}, process_response);
  } else {
    alert("No ID supplied");
  }
}

// encapsulate the lot within a function scope called on document ready
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  // hook the submit action on the form

  var frm = document.getElementById("quick-form");
  frm.addEventListener("submit", frm_submit, false);

  /**
    * function to handle form submit, and request data from server
    * @param {Event} event
    */
  function frm_submit(event) {
    // stop the form submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    // grab the ID and send AJAX request if not (empty / only whitespace)
    var ID = this.elements.ordernum.value;
    if (/\S/.test(ID)) {
      ajax_request(this.action, {"action" : "fetch", "ordernum" : ID}, process_response);
    } else {
      alert("No ID supplied");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="quick-form">
  <input type="text" name="ordernum" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```